# Does Anyone Migrate from Neo4jClient to .Net Bolt driver Neo4j 3

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

we are using neo4j in our engine by Neo4jClient, 
Does anyone migrate from Neo4jClient to Neo4j New Bolt Driver ?

-Is there any sample for basic and advanced queries ?

-Is there something like CypherFluentQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use both now.
i take advantage of the bolt protocol and session / transaction mgmt while keeping the usefulness of CypherFluentQuery

so it looks something like

```
private ICypherFluentQuery getSomething(){...}
private void execute(ICypherFluentQuery q){
    ...
    using (var s = _driver.Session())
    {
         ...
         s.Run(q.Query.QueryText, q.Query.QueryParameters);
         ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: How do you cast back into C# classes??

Comment: cloud you please send some sample query like group by or return multi collections

Answer (score 1):

There is no `CypherFluentQuery` for the `neo4j-dotnet-driver`, the only documentation I'm aware of is via the `readme.md` of the [github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver) repo and the `neo4j` [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0-SNAPSHOT/#driver-manual-index).

It'll be a big task going from one to the other, mainly due to the lack of `CFQ` and the object mapping `Neo4jClient` gives you. :/

Comment: For those who don't know, Chris has been working on wrapping the official bolt driver within the Neo4jClient project to provide the best of both worlds. The beta is here: https://www.myget.org/feed/cskardon/package/nuget/Neo4jClient

Thanks, Chris!